# Button Click Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

I'm using buttons which when clicked on move fractionally down.

```
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

The problem I'm having is users occasionally click right at the top of button, either just under or on the buttons border.
When the click goes down the button moves down and the cursor is no longer above the button.  As a result a click is not actually registered.
I've replicated this in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJNEb/3/

If you click right on the top edge of the button, the button moves, but the click event handler is not fired.  I'm seeing this behaviour in IE, Firefox, Chrome.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the button inside a div and add the event on the div, this way you can keep your effect without over complicating your code.

Another way would be to treat the mousedown and mouseup events and check if the cursor position has changed

Comment: Oddly surrounding with DIV does not resolve the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/sLmvS/

Answer (score 1):

Basically `click()` event is disturbed by the `:active` state moving objects.

[Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468967/1654265)

Your solution by the way is a little different from the one of that answer;

Starting from the solution proposed by @cdanisor, you need to use `mouseup()` (in order to preserve the moving effect of the button AND to fire the event only when mouse is released)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kEQjU/

```
<div id="alertMe">
    <div class="button red"> test</div>
</div>

$("#alertMe").mouseup(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Obviously you can preserve the keyboard compatibility by using a `button` instead of a `div`, and binding the same function to the `keyup` event:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kEQjU/1/

```
<div id="alertMe">
    <input type="button" class="button red" value="test" /> 
</div>

$("#alertMe").mouseup(function() {
alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
$("#alertMe").keyup(function() {
alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can see this is working.  One minor issue with this is it breaks keyboard compatibility in that you cannot press space on the button to get a button click.  I'm guessing you could just have a mouseup and on click in some fashion.  It also starts to get messy as I'd need to go around a considerable number of buttons to make this work.  I'm still hoping for a better solution.  Possibly I need to use some less elegant buttons!

Comment: And btw the keyboard problem was present in your original fiddle too: why using `div`s as `button`s when you can style `button`s directly ? :)

Comment: I started with buttons, and ended up with div's whilst trying to find a solution.  I must have copied this into the jsfiddle.  Thanks for the update